# My Internet Explorer (version 11) doesn't load external scripts

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

That's it. I dont know why, but my Internet explorer doesnt load external js files. JS is enabled on the browser. And the files are working on other browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Opera or even Safari...
I dont know why really...
I need help real fast...

head-tag:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Antonio Bueno González" />
    <meta name="description" content="Descripción de la página web" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Palabras clave" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <title>tapeHD</title>
</head>
```

P.D.: Furthermore, there're no error in console... It's quite strange.

Comment: Why do you load 3 (different) versions of jquery? What happens on the network tab of the console?

Comment: That's it the library (2 versions for different IE version, I guess), and my own jquery document; with my functions... What I dont know is which version of JQuery use... BTW, it happens nothing in the console

Comment: Bring up the developer tools, switch to the Network tab, press the play button, then refresh the page. You should be able to see what is loading there. Additionally, IE can be funny about loading scripts if you're loading the page from your hard drive (not a server) - but it'll tell you what's blocked in the info bar.

Comment: Have you tried using `//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js` without the protocol? Maybe its a protocol mismatch.

Comment: I don't understand too much what happens... I think all loads perfectly... http://gyazo.com/f379303ab6c4643b3dfff491487417fe  The problem is that I receive some error from fonts, that it doesnt happen in the other browsers; anyway, fonts is not the problem...

Comment: It's not the protocol, obviously, if I remove it, JQuery won't work... It's not an external folder, it's a web link

Comment: @Antonio - that's not true. Omitting a protocol allows the link to use the protocol its instantiated from. It won't work if the site you are pointing at doesn't support the protocol, but a mismatch can also cause issues. Thats why google hosted libraries links to jQuery like this: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` - The `//` indicates it needs the protocol inheritance, if it was a single `/` it would refer to the root of whatever file system you are on.

Comment: Ah ok thx. So, it can be because Im not running the web page on a server. Ok, im gonna download wamp. P.D.: Which version of JQuery do you recommend me? Is this one OK? //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Ah yes, you're right, I forgot to mention that doing that locally will try to get to the `file` protocol, on which google doesn't exist of course, so you need to add a protocol there. And yes, the version you have there should be good for whatever you want to do. If you don't need support for IE6, 7 or 8 however, you might want to consider using jQuery 2.

Comment: OK perfect... more problems... I'm sorry about being annoying... I have just installed Wamp server, I have move my project folders into the www folder... Now, I click on wamp > my project > proyect, and it doesnt work... "this web page is not available"...

Comment: Ok DONE, i wrote in a bad way the link xd. Anyway, it worked, it was the server. Thanks too much dudes!

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar problem, until I discovered that the script contained an new function that only Google managed to run, whereas IE did not know it yet and issued an error message, so the entire script did not load at all !!!